# How do I make a scrollable client without destroying my interface?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

Okay, I have been having an impossible time with ScrollPanes. Here is my constructor:

```
private static JTextField field = new JTextField();
private static JTextArea pane = new JTextArea();
public Client(){
    JButton close = new JButton("Close");
    close.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_C);
    close.addActionListener(new closeList());
    JButton send = new JButton("Send");
    send.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_S);
    send.addActionListener(new sendList());
    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));
    buttonPanel.add(send);
    buttonPanel.add(close);

    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(pane);

    pane.setLineWrap(true);
    pane.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    pane.setEditable(false);        
    Container tupper = getContentPane();
    tupper.add(field, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    tupper.add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    tupper.add(scroll, BorderLayout.EAST);
    tupper.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
}
```

So, the scrollpane is there, but id doesn't do anything. I've tried using bar in stead of pane, but it's all the same. All the examples online utilize some special awt layout. Is there ANY way to make my textarea scrollable?

Answer (score 2):

You're adding `pane` twice: once as a child of `scroll` and once directly to `tupper`. A component can only have one parent at a time. Try removing this line:

```
tupper.add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```